# How to use Thickbox with jqGrid on a ASP.NET WebForms Page?

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid, thickbox, webforms

I have a asp.net webforms page in which I'm using the jqGrid component. The problem is that thickbox is not working on the links inside jqGrid (ajax).

I got this peace of code on [Gupta's blog](http://blog.anupamgupta.info/) but I don't know how to add it as I'm using the jqGrid component for ASP.NET. Can anyone help ? Thanks.

```
gridComplete: function(){
// ThickBox - this allows any dynamically created links that use thickbox to work!
tb_init('a.thickbox, area.thickbox, input.thickbox');//pass where to apply thickbox
imgLoader = new Image();// preload image
imgLoader.src = tb_pathToImage;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may want to consider using the explicit call to thickbox.  put this on the onclick for your links.

```
inline popup:
tb_show('title','#TB_inline?height=155&width=300&inlineId=hiddenModalContent&modal=true');
or iframed page:
tb_show('title','myPage.aspx?TB_iframe=true&height=155&width=300&modal=true');
```

take a look at the documentation on the thickbox website for more examples [jquery thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/)